# Check empty editbox objects in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have listview with N number of rows and the same number EditText object. User should enter values in each EditText, if hi misses one of entries application have to put focus on that field.

This is how I check entries:

```
    for(int i=0;i<listOfInouts.size();i++){

     View view=lv.getChildAt(i);
     EditText editText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMyEntry);

     if (editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()
     {
       // Toast - here goes toast message
       editText.setFocusable(true);
     } 
     else
     {
       // do something else
     }

}
```

But this code doesn't work well. Is this correct way to check values insied EditText?

Comment: use StringUtility.isEmptyOrNull instead.

Comment: your way is wrong buddy, in the list you you have more then a edit text then you definitely have a adapter, then why should you taken for loop here.

Comment: your this task will perform in getView() method of adapter at there you can easily perform your job, and yes at a time one single view can get the focus, which did you described above only your last view can get focus.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())
     { 
       // Toast - here goes toast message 
       editText.setFocusable(true); 
     }  
     else 
     { 
       // do something else 
     }
```

try this code

and the view which is used in a list view get recycled , so u cant get the exact view at each  position (Only Visible view get correct values )